# Display last 3 items of the array in <tbody>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays:

```
    const thArray = ["Name", "User ID"];
    const tdArray = [
      ["Amy", "3016762"],
      ["Mary", "8801335"],
      ["Sam", "8801345"],
      ["Michael", "3016234"],
      ["Doris", "3016566"],
      ["Emily", "3016810"]
    ];
```

I would want to display the last 3 objects in tdArray in tbody, my code now is displaying all the objects in tdArray. How and where can I place my loop?

```
    <Table>
         <thead>
                <tr>
                    {thArray.map((prop, key) => {
                     return <th key={key}>{prop}</th>;
                  })}
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 {tdArray.map((prop, key) => {
                  return (
                   <tr key={key}>
                    {prop.map((prop, key) => {
                     return <td key={key}>{prop}</td>;
                  })}
                  </tr>
                 );
               })}
           </tbody>
    </Table>
```

Comment: I suggest you store your last three items in a variable and then use that to render those items.

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create new array with last 3 items from your base array, and then map it like you want to render proper information like this:

```
const tdArray = [
              ["Amy", "3016762"],
              ["Mary", "8801335"],
              ["Sam", "8801345"],
              ["Michael", "3016234"],
              ["Doris", "3016566"],
              ["Emily", "3016810"]
            ];



            const lastItem = tdArray.length - 1;


            const newArray = [];
            newArray.push(tdArray[lastItem], tdArray[lastItem - 1], tdArray[lastItem -2]);
```

And in table component go through new created array like this:

```
<Table>
         <thead>
                <tr>
                    {newArray .map((prop, key) => {
                     return <th key={key}>{prop}</th>;
                  })}
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 {tdArray.map((prop, key) => {
                  return (
                   <tr key={key}>
                    {prop.map((prop, key) => {
                     return <td key={key}>{prop}</td>;
                  })}
                  </tr>
                 );
               })}
           </tbody>
    </Table>
```